# Error: hd0 cannot get c/h/s

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I have an old notebook and i try to install windows 10 (mini os) and ubuntu 22.04 with dual boot, i install windows 10 and then try to enter to ubuntu live from a usb but i have this error that says "cannot get c/h/s values".
I read the cmos battery could be the problem but its welded and i cant find other solution.

(first time using linux, i want it with dual boot because its mom notebook but windows its slow and i need the notebook to study, also sorry for bad english)

Answer (score 0):

I just try on another usb port and it work lol